# Rspec spec returns a LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

Returned to my app after a years absence and I could not get:

```
rspec spec
```

to run. It ran a year ago and I thought I had left it at a good point to pick up again when I had the time, but not so ... So I decided to update Ruby and Rails and all went well with the updates, bundle install etc, so now I have Ruby 2.1.1p76 and Rails 4.1.0 running.

I ran the same command shown above and this is the flag I got:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails410/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in
`require': dlopen(/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails410/extensions
/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/pg-0.17.1/pg_ext.bundle, 9): 
Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libpq.dylib
Reason: image not found - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/
ruby-  2.1.1@rails410/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/pg-0.17.1/pg_ext.bundle
```

I noticed that I have a LoadError but I am not sure what I need to do to correct that. Also two lines down from that I see 'Reason: image not found' and here I am even further away from a solution.

Hopefully someone has the expertise and generosity to give me a pointer in the right direction?

Comment: Did you migrate the test database? Try running `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: Thanks dmtri. I ran the rake db:test:prepare but it aborted with the same LoadError. Do I have to update to a later Postgresql ... currently I have 9.2 ... that is the posters.app for the Mac .. thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I am not exactly sure. Can you try doing `bundle install` and redo `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: Ok ... I ran it again after the bundle install and the same LoadError ... I will have to do more research ... thanks for your time "dmtri".

Answer (score 0):

I installed postgres using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Running `brew info postgres` suggested that I install the pg gem including `ARCHFLAGS`. I guess this might be system-specific, but the following worked for me:

```
gem uninstall pg
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```